# Animate adding/deleting items from todo list using transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-transition, vuejs-transition-group

I have a todo list that is based on the example provided in the official vuejs documentation.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/87Lfbzng/

```
<ul class="todo-list">
  <li v-for="todo in filteredTodos" class="todo" :key="todo.id" :class="{ completed: todo.completed, editing: todo == editedTodo }">
    <div class="view">
      <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" v-model="todo.completed">
      <label @dblclick="editTodo(todo)">{{ todo.title }}</label>
      <button class="destroy" @click="removeTodo(todo)"></button>
    </div>
    <input class="edit" type="text" v-model="todo.title" v-todo-focus="todo == editedTodo" @blur="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.enter="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.esc="cancelEdit(todo)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

The issue with this is that the items are removed/added instantly, with no animation. If I implement the `transition` tags as per the official documentation take effect. [VueJS transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

I've tried putting the transition tags inside the `ul` and that didn't work either.

My current attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/87Lfbzng/

CSS

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to
/* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */

  {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Markup

```
<transition name="fade">
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li v-for="todo in filteredTodos" class="todo" :key="todo.id" :class="{ completed: todo.completed, editing: todo == editedTodo }">
      <div class="view">
        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" v-model="todo.completed">
        <label @dblclick="editTodo(todo)">{{ todo.title }}</label>
        <button class="destroy" @click="removeTodo(todo)"></button>
      </div>
      <input class="edit" type="text" v-model="todo.title" v-todo-focus="todo == editedTodo" @blur="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.enter="doneEdit(todo)" @keyup.esc="cancelEdit(todo)">
    </li>

  </ul>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `ul` tag with a `transition` tag. You then add the **tag** attribute to the `transition` tag with the value of **ul**.

```
<transition-group name="fade" tag="ul" class="todo-list">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ducwpeam/

The official documentation covers this, using `ul` as an example: [VueJs Documentation: List Moves](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with plain css

```
.view {
   animation: fade-anim 0.4s ease
}
@keyframes fade-anim {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping your `ul` only inside that `transition`... this will do nothing .. because your `ul` is static :

> Vue provides a transition wrapper component, allowing you to add entering/leaving transitions for any element or component in the following contexts:

- > Conditional rendering (using v-if)
- > Conditional display (using v-show)
- > Dynamic components
- > Component root nodes

Instead you need to wrap your `li` elements inside a `transition` tag and this time it will be a `transition-group` because you have more than two elements :

```
<ul>
 <transition-group name="fade">
  <li></li>
  <li></li> 
   ...
 </transition-group>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtkj1hbL/)